# Pyspark - Add Rows By Group

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pyspark 2.2 I am essentially trying to add rows by user.

If I have my main Dataframe that looks like:

```
main_list = [["a","bb",5], ["d","cc",10],["d","bb",11]]
main_pd = pd.DataFrame(main_list, columns = ['user',"group", 'value'])
main_df = spark.createDataFrame(main_pd)
main_df.show()

+----+-----+-----+
|user|group|value|
+----+-----+-----+
|   a|   bb|    5|
|   d|   cc|   10|
|   d|   bb|   11|
+----+-----+-----+
```

I then have a key Dataframe where I would like to have every user have every group value

User `d` has a row for group `bb` and `cc`. I would like user `a` to have the same.

```
key_list = [["bb",10],["cc",17]]
key_pd = pd.DataFrame(key_list, columns = ['group', 'value'])
key_df = spark.createDataFrame(key_pd)

main_df.join(key_df, ["group"], how ="outer").show()
```

But my result returns:

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|group|user|value|value|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|   cc|   d|   10|   17|
|   bb|   a|    5|   10|
|   bb|   d|   11|   10|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

Here are the schemas of each Dataframe:

```
main_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)

key_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

Essentially I would like the result to be:

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|group|user|value|value|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|   cc|   d|   10|   17|
|   bb|   a|    5|   10|
|   cc|   a| Null|   17|
|   bb|   d|   11|   10|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I don't think the full outer join will accomplish this with a `coalesce` so I had also experimented with `row_number/rank`

Comment: do you want every user to have all the distinct groups?

Comment: yes thats correct. I want every user to have all the distinct groups in the key Dataframe and if its not present in the main df, then they would receive the default value in the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the user-group combinations with a `cross join`, then use a `left join` on the `maind_df` to generate missing rows and then `left join` the result with key_df.

```
users = main_df.select("user").distinct()
groups = main_df.select("group").distinct()
user_group = users.crossJoin(groups)

all_combs = user_group.join(main_df, (main_df.user == user_group.user) & (main_df.group == user_group.group), "left").select(user_group.user,user_group.group,main_df.value)
all_combs.join(key_df, key_df.group == all_combs.group, "left").show()
```